# Is it possible to write data to google sheets using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm using the Google charts query for selecting a data from google sheets and after processing the data, I want to write or push it back into google sheets. Is it possible to do this using JavaScript?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#what_can_this_api_do  ?

Answer (score 2):

Good news: yes, you can do with JavaScript.

More info: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js#prerequisites

Also, don't forget: with JS you can do [XMLHTTPRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), which allows you to work with a lot of API's. :-)

Have fun!